# Stationarity of Time Series with $\cos(\pi t)$ in it

Tags: time-series, stationarity

So I have a time series $Y_t = 1 + \cos(\pi t)X_0$ where $X_t$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$ and I'm trying to determine it's stationarity. But I'm not sure about some of this math here. So far I have:

$E[Y_t]= E[1]+E[\cos(\pi t)X_0]=1+0=1$ and then for the covariance function:

$Cov(Y_t, Y_{t-k})=E[(1 + \cos(\pi t)X_0)(1 + \cos(\pi (t-k))X_0)\\= 1 + E[\cos(\pi t)X_0] +E[\cos(\pi (t-k))X_0] = 1+0+0=1 $

but I'm not sure if I've done this correctly. If I had to guess though, this time series would be stationary because of the nature of most cyclical functions and $cos(\pi t)$ looks stationary in it's variance

Comment: Did you mean to type that $X_0$ is normally distributed instead of $X_t$?

Comment: @SOULed_Outt oh in the quesiton it says ${X_t}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. r.v. with mean 0 and variance $\sigma ^2$ but I guess I am taking some liberties with saying $E[X_0]=0$

Comment: Okay. I see some issues with you covariance function. You seem to have expanded the product incorrectly.

Comment: $$(1 + \cos (\pi t) X_0) ( 1 + \cos(\pi (t-k)) X_0) = 1 +\cos(\pi (t-k)) X_0 + \cos (\pi t) X_0 + \cos (\pi t)  \cos(\pi (t-k)) X^2_0$$

Comment: @SOULed_Outt ah ok thanks. So if I take the expected value of each of those terms would i be left with 1 from the first and then $E[cos(πt)cos(π(t−k))X^{2}_0)$ is what I'm not sure about... I would say 0 because the $cos $ is deterministic

Comment: The cosine functions can be treated as constants so you can pull them outside of the expected value.

Comment: Then note that $\text{Var}(X_0) = E(X^2_0) - \left[ E(X_0)\right]^2 = E(X^2_0) $

Comment: @SOULed_Outt awesome, u answered my question, thanks so much for the help

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure about what to do afterwards to determine stationarity, but if you are sure then please consider posting your answer so we all can learn from it.

Comment: What is the variance of $X_{1/2}$? How does it compare with the variance of $X_0$?